# Understanding node-mariasql example code

Tags: node.js, mariadb

I see the following code on the [node-mariasql](https://github.com/mscdex/node-mariasql#examples) library -

```
var inspect = require('util').inspect;
var Client = require('mariasql');

var c = new Client();
c.connect({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  user: 'foo',
  password: 'bar',
  db: 'mydb'
});

c.on('connect', function() {
   console.log('Client connected');
 })
 .on('error', function(err) {
   console.log('Client error: ' + err);
 })
 .on('close', function(hadError) {
   console.log('Client closed');
 });

var pq = c.prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id AND name = :name');

c.query(pq({ id: 1337, name: 'Frylock' }))
 .on('result', function(res) {
   res.on('row', function(row) {
     console.log('Result row: ' + inspect(row));
   })
   .on('error', function(err) {
     console.log('Result error: ' + inspect(err));
   })
   .on('end', function(info) {
     console.log('Result finished successfully');
   });
 })
 .on('end', function() {
   console.log('Done with all results');
 });

c.end();
```

The output for this has been specified as -

```
/* output:
    Client connected
    Query #1 row: [ 'first query' ]
    Query #1 finished successfully
    Query #2 was aborted
    Query #3 row: [ 'third query' ]
    Query #3 finished successfully
    Done with all queries
    Client closed
 */
```

To me the `c.connect` looks to be an asynchronous call. So then shouldn't the bottom part of the code be placed inside the c.on('connect') callback? Otherwise what is the guarantee that the connection would have already opened by the time I do `c.query` or `c.prepare`

**The bottom part of the code**.

```
var pq = c.prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id AND name = :name');

c.query(pq({
    id: 1337,
    name: 'Frylock'
}))
    .on('result', function (res) {
    res.on('row', function (row) {
        console.log('Result row: ' + inspect(row));
    })
        .on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Result error: ' + inspect(err));
    })
        .on('end', function (info) {
        console.log('Result finished successfully');
    });
})
    .on('end', function () {
    console.log('Done with all results');
});

c.end();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql protocol requires you to wait for previous command to complete before sending next one, and because of this most clients have some kind of [internal queue](https://github.com/mscdex/node-mariasql/blob/master/lib/Client.js#L259) and [move to next command in the queue](https://github.com/mscdex/node-mariasql/blob/master/lib/Client.js#L362) automatically. This code for example does not execute 3 queries in parallel:

```
c.query('select sleep(1)');
c.query('select sleep(2)');
c.query('select 1', console.log);
```

Instead, it'll output "select 1" result after 3 seconds. So the answer to "what is the guarantee that the connection would have already opened" is "client design guarantees this to you"